# 500 Internal Server Error al configurar un subdominio nuevo en .htaccess

Tags: apache2, centos6

En el `.htaccess` tengo dos subdominios configurados que apuntan a diferentes carpetas.

```
###ACB DVA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} acb-dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dva_demo/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /dva_demo/$1 [L]
```

y

```
### DVA
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dva/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /dva/$1 [L]
```

Al intentar entrar en **acb-dva.demo.net** recibo el error 500. Si comento el **dva.demo.net** funciona bien.

Como podría diferenciar los sub- dominios ?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. ¿Cómo estás configurando los subdominios? ¿Cuál es el contenido del virtualhost? ¿Qué mensaje te devuelven los logs de apache cuando recibes un HTTP 500?

Comment: Toda la configuración se hace mediante el fichero htaccess.

El mensaje es:

request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

Comment: ¿Necesitas que al acceder a `http://acb-dva.demo.net/` te redirija a qué página? Actualmente la redirección llevaría a `http://acb-dva.demo.net/dva/`

Comment: Actualmente la página http://acb-dva.demo.net/ devuelve error 500 porque coincide con las dos reglas, pero quiero que me abra el contenido de la carpeta /dva_demo/

Comment: Intenta cambiar `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]` por `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]` y `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} acb-dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]` a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^acb-dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]`

Por que según como tienes la regex `dva.demo.net` entra en conficto con ambas, de esta manera no hacen match ambas.

Comment: @Adrián Gracias. Puedes escribir una respuesta para ponerla como valida ? Saludos

Comment: De nada. Me alegro haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiar la siguiente directiva:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
```

Por la siguiente:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
```

Y esta directiva:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} acb-dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
```

Por esta:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^acb-dva\.demo\.net$ [NC]
```

Según como tienes la regex `dva.demo.net` entra en conficto con ambas configuraciones. Añadiendo `^` al principio obligas que comience siempre por el dominio.